# lightbox focus on input, only works after refresh

Tags: javascript, focus, refresh, lightbox, onload

I have a login box that pops up when you click on the login button, and that lightbox will have a login form loaded into it.

I have tried setting 
onLoad="document.loginForm.login.focus()" to try and set the focus on the login box when the page loads.

However, this seems to only work, after you refresh the login form in the lightbox, not the parent documents behind it.

I have tried adding a timeout option to the function as I thought it may be a timing issue, but this does not seem to have worked.

Does anyone have any ideas why it works after a refresh, but not on first load?

Thanks
Eds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should help you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("iframe").load(function(){
        window.frames[0].document.forms['loginForm'].login.focus();
    });
});
```

If you have more than one iframe in your page, then give an id to your target iframe and use `$("#myIframeId")` instead of `$("iframe")`

Comment: where abouts does this need to go?
eds

Comment: oh sorry :) this should be on your parent page, which contains your iframe popup

Comment: and consider that you have form named "loginForm" which contains input named "login" in your iframe document

Comment: ok great thanks, does it need to go into an onload in <body>, or is it a script that needs to go into <head>?

Comment: no, it shouldn't go into onload, it uses jQuery, so `$(document).ready` means that all stuff inside will work after the document is loaded.

Comment: and one more thing... this kind of exploration of child iframe content can be done **ONLY** if both protocol and domain of parent and child iframes is the same.

Comment: I ended up getting the below to work from within the login form page:

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
var t=setTimeout("document.loginForm.login.focus();",500);
 </script>

i had been using the timeout incorrectly, and needed to add this script after the form, so the form could load first.

Comment: I think i may have also had two variables with the same name of login, and thats why sometimes it was getting focus, and sometimes it was not. My variable is now called login_box :P Thanks for your help though!!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `document.loginForm.login.focus()` on button click event.

Comment: Calling it from an onclick event from within the lightbox seems to work correctly, however, Im not sure how to add it to my login button on the parent page.

my onclick to show the lightbox is:

onclick=\"TINY.box.show({iframe:'/site/main/login/login-form.php',
    width:350,height:250,fixed:false})\"

Comment: what JS library are you using?

Comment: I do have a jquery script loaded into the parent page, but other than that, none